# Runtime Casting of Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics, casting, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I have a command processing routine that needs to get a Processor object from my IOC container and call the ProcessCommand on it, the processors are concrete object implementing a generic interface:

```
public interface ICommandProcessor<in T> where T : Command
{        
    Error ProcessCommand(T command);
}
```

the problem I have is that when I try to retreive the processor I only have a reference to the command object via the base class (Command) so I do not know the type of T (except at runtime)

I have introduced a second non-generic interface

```
public interface ICommandProcessorGeneric
{

}

public interface ICommandProcessor<in T>:ICommandProcessorGeneric where T : Command
{        
    Error ProcessCommand(T command);
}
```

and can retreive the processor from the IOC container as follows:

```
 protected virtual CommandProcessingResult RecognizeAndProcessCommand<T>(T command) where T : Command
 {
    ICommandProcessor<T> commandProcessor;

    try
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format( "---- Looking for processor for type {0}", command.GetType().Name));
        var g = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<ICommandProcessorGeneric>(command.GetType().Name);                
        commandProcessor = g as ICommandProcessor<T>;  //returns null!!
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("---- Got Processor {0}", g.GetType().Name));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the exception
    }
    return commandProcessor.ProcessCommand(command);
}
```

the problem is that commandProcessor is then null as T is Command, whereas at runtime I know that T is a derived type.  the object g returned from the IOC container is the correct processorm however I cannot see how I can cast g to a type that will allow me to access the ProcessCommand method.

I should also point out that the call into this method has no way of determining the type of the command at compile time as the command is retreived from a database by reference only to at ID field and deserialised.

Comment: If you are casting inside the generic method, you're using it wrong. Ideally you should constraint your `RecognizeAndProcessCommand` method with  `ICommandProcessor<T>`

Comment: If you avoid using the `ServiceLocator` pattern in this case, and instead inject the `ICommandProcessor<T>` into the instance (or method, if you really have to) containing `RecognizeAndProcessCommand<T>`, would that solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I've written a blog post on this very issue](http://davunderscorei.co.uk/programming/specific-generic-pattern/).

So basically what I've done in the past is to create an abstract base class for your Command Processor along with a generic one:

```
public abstract class CommandProcessor
{
    public abstract Error ProcessCommand(Command command);
}

public abstract class CommandProcessor<TCommand> where TCommand : Command
{
    public override Error ProcessCommand(Command command)
    {
        if (command is TCommand == false)
            throw new ArgumentException("command should be of type TCommand");

        var cast = (TCommand)command;

        return this.ProcessCommand(cast);
    }

    public abstract Error ProcessCommand(TCommand command);
}
```

Now you don't need to do anything special dependant of what type of Command you are using:

```
protected virtual CommandProcessingResult RecogniseAndProccessCommand<T>
    (T command) where T : Command
{
    var commandProcessor = (CommandProcessor)ServiceLocator.GetInstance<ICommandProcessorGeneric>(typeof(T).Name);

    return commandProcessor.ProcessCommand(command);
}
```

Comment: The word "Command" looks weird to me now... typed it too many times.

Comment: This casting of Command to TCommand is what I am trying to get away from.

Comment: The point is that your `ServiceLocator` will get the correct version of `CommandProcessor`, which will have the correct implementation of `ProcessCommand` but you can still call the base `ProcessCommand` at compile time without having to worry about the type at that time.

Comment: apologies, that is exactly what I have done in the end, the casting being done in the abstract base class is fine.